# In Python, why after iterating over an iterator, the iterator doesn't "work" anymore?

Tags: python

In the below code, why do I get different outputs? After iterating over the first `arr`, I can't make a list out of it (it's empty). However, if I do the same before iterating, as seen in the second part of the code, the set gets created, but when iterating after that, it seems like `arr2` is empty.
Why does this happen and how to avoid/fix it?

```
arr = map(int, [1,2,3])

for item in arr:
    print(item)    

myset = set(arr)
print(myset)

# Output:
# 1
# 2
# 3
set()    

########################

arr2 = map(int, [1,2,3])

newset = set(arr2)
print(newset)

for item in arr2:
    print(item)

# Output:
# {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: You can make `arr2` a list to preserve its contents `arr2 = list(map(int, [1,2,3]))`

Comment: Yeah, I know, thanks. However, why does this happen if I don't transform it into a list?

Comment: What did you expect? What should the iterator do after being consumed?

Comment: Iterators are one-use by design; there's no way to "go back to the beginning", hence you need to store the output of an iterator in a container - like a list - if you want to be able to iterate over the same values again, and you weren't iterating over a container in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote the comment before reading the answers of the already asked question.